# NetApp: Cannot import private key from an external CA

Tags: certificate, netapp, private-key, import, ontap

Using the ONTAP System Manager, I'm trying to add a certificate according to the [docs](https://docs.netapp.com/us-en/ontap/authentication/manage-certificates-sm-task.html#install-cs-cert). Unfortunately, whenever I try to import the private key file, I get the following error:

```
No valid private keys can be imported from the selected file.
```

When I copy & paste the private key and click on *Save*, it also fails, but with another error message:

```
The private key is not in a valid format. Paste in the private key, including the "BEGIN" and "END" tags.
```

My private key file contains the following "BEGIN" and "END" tags:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
...
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----` indicates that you are using a PEM encoded key in PKCS#1 format. NetApp expects the private key to be in PEM encoded PKCS#8 format. You can convert your private key to PKCS#8 using `openssl`:

```
openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -inform PEM -outform PEM -nocrypt -in key.pem -out key8.pem
```